# Microsoft Graph API Shared Calendar IDs inconsistent between users

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365api, outlook-restapi

My application allows users to schedule events on shared calendars and allows other users to potentially reschedule or cancel those events. I ask for the `Calendar.ReadWrite.Shared` permission to enable this.

It appears that if two users have access to a shared calendar, the ID value returned from the `GET /me/calendars` is different for the two users. Is there a consistent, unique ID value that can be used to correlate shared calendars across users?

Comment: Hi @Emily! I'm running into the same issue for a similar use case. Did you find a suitable workaround? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is not a unique ID value that is shared across all of the shared calendar instances.

Calendars in Exchange server are built on top of mail folders (just like appointments are built on top of messages). Each folder in a user's mailbox has an ID assigned when it's created.

When a user shares their calendar with another user (the delegate), what happens behind the scenes is that when the delegate clicks the "Accept" button in the sharing mail, the server creates a **copy** of the shared calendar in the delegate's mailbox, and sets up syncing so that the copy stays in sync with the original. This is important to your question, because when you access the shared calendar as the delegate, you're not accessing the calendar in the owner's mailbox, you're accessing the copy. Because a copy is created in each delegate's mailbox, the ID is different for each copy.

The `owner` property on the calendar resource tells you which mailbox the original calendar lives in, but it isn't enough to correlate it with other copies in other mailboxes. The `name` property is editable, so it can't be relied on here.

Comment: Hey @Jason - given that shared calendars are used by multiple users (by definition), what's MSFT's recommendation for identifying these calendars as equivalent? Is there an `iCalUid` equivalent for calendars?

Comment: I don't really have one. There's no good way to do this. Could you explain your scenario a bit?

Comment: What about using a special event placed on calendars, then using the iCalUId as the calendar's unique ID? The event would have to have no attendees. I understand that the user could delete it.

Comment: @JasonJohnston - Sure thing. It's actually very similar to Emily's use case. We have an application where multiple users are scheduling events on shared calendars. Sometimes a user needs to reschedule or cancel an event on a shared calendar they have edit access to, but did not create themselves. So after an event is created, I'll have the calendar ID of the creator. But I have no way of identifying which calendar this corresponds to for any other user in our application.

Comment: The best I can think of is to store the iCalUid of the event along with the owner of the calendar. Then if you need to find it for a particular user, check all calendars in their mailbox that match the owner for an event with that iCalUid. It's not great and involves multiple calls, but it should at least get your scenario working. You might want to file a feature request on our UserVoice: https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com

Answer (score 0):

I use for this a calendar of an account with given privilegies to other people.
So I can access to this cal from each account with

```
/{$user}/calendar/{$cal}/
```

Also I can Sync with delta:

```
/{$user}/calendarView/delta?
```

But this works only for "one" calendar, at this moment there is no "delta" for an explizit calendar.