# Does Microsoft Graph API Subscription creation require specific permissions?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I am trying to use the create subscription API to open a subscription channel on a calendar's events such that we can receive updates when interviewers respond to the interview.

I have tried many variations to get this request to work:

#### Permission Scopes

I have gone through the oauth process to retrieve graph access tokens for a user with the following permission Scopes:

- `Mail.Send`
- `Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared`
- `User.ReadBasic.All`

#### Successful Calendar Event Creation

Using the access tokens with the above scopes, before attempting to create the subscription, I add an event with `{eventId}` to a shared calendar, let's say with the [user relative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46943347/microsoft-graph-api-shared-calendar-ids-inconsistent-between-users) id of `{sharedCalendarId}`.

#### Subscription Creation Attempts

Using the same access tokens to create the same Authorization header with permission scopes listed above, I consistently receive the same `ExtensionError` response. Below I will list the various permutations of request I have made to the graph API.

*Urls Attempted*

I have sent each permutation of the subscription POST requests to the following URLs:

- `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions`
- `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/subscriptions`

*Request Headers*

- `Content-Type: application/json`
- `Authorization: Bearer {authToken}`

*Request Bodies Attempted*

The `changeType` and `notificationUrl`, and `expirationDateTime` are the same for all requests.
I have tried 3 different variations on the `resource` string, and have tried the request with and without the `clientState`.

First I tried the fully identified resource and added `clientState`:

```json
{
  "changeType": "created,updated",
  "notificationUrl": "https://{domain-with-valid-https-certs}/calendar/microsoft/notifications",
  "resource": "users/{userPrincipalName}/calendars/{sharedCalendarId}/events",
  "clientState": "{thisIsLimitedTo128Characters}",
  "expirationDateTime": "2018-05-23T21:02:45.487Z"
}
```

Next, I abandoned `clientState` for the sake of narrowing down the problem and I used `me` instead of {userPrincipalName}:

```json
{
  ...
  "resource": "me/calendars/{sharedCalendarId}/events"
}
```

Then I abandoned the shared calendar to see if that was the problem and used a resource that's an example in the docs.

```json
{
  ...
  "resource": "me/events"
}
```

#### Error Response Received

While I seem to receive the validation request to the `notificationUrl` provided (and the server responds appropriately) the request to create the subscription then responds with this kind of error:

```cs
{
  code: "ExtensionError",
  message: "Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: Forbidden; Reason: Forbidden]",
  innerError: {
    "request-id": "0d86a983-ea50-4226-905c-38f0e8f12308",
    date: "2018-05-23T03:55:38"
  }
}
```

What's confusing is that I am attempting to create this subscription on a calendar I have just successfully created or changed and event, so the `403` seems like it should not be related to access to the resource.

Are there specific permissions or scopes that need to be granted for us to successfully create subscriptions to a calendar's events?
Is there a different API we should be using?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you're new here, I recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips. Your question is lacking sufficient detail to help the community help you. Please include the code/payload you're sending to the API, not just the error that was returned.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur I added a more detailed description of my requests.

Comment: Some more request Ids:
- `bb2425ff-e2e2-40b0-8f1b-26fe2541bb2e`
- `992bc9ab-e53a-47ea-b171-f5367c8a9455`
- `173e9c7a-0dba-483d-a765-58b444313de2`

Answer (score 2):

In order to subscribe to a resource, you minimally need read access to the resource. So for events, you would need `Calendars.Read`. Since you have more than that, you should be fine. ([Reference](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/subscription_post_subscriptions))

I believe your problem is that you are not including `expirationDateTime` in the payload. This is a required property (documented [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/webhooks), arguably not the best place for this to be listed). Set it to a value equal to or less than the maximum for calendar, 4230 minutes ([Reference](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/subscription#maximum-length-of-subscription-per-resource-type)).

Comment: Sorry, I am including the `expirationDateTime`, I will update my question again.

Comment: I was hoping that my `expirationDateTime` was too far in the future and that was the issue, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Also, I would think I'd receive a more specific error message and a 400 if my request is actually malformed.

Comment: For the purposes of reducing the number of variables, you may want to request `Calendars.ReadWrite` and focus on just `/me/events` for the time being. Shared calendars introduce a bit more complexity (i.e. how were they shared, do you have access, etc.) and since it's happening to both user and shared calendars, you may as well keep things simply.

Comment: I agree with Marc. I'd also suggest trying to create the subscription from Graph Explorer using the same payload to eliminate your app from the equation.

Comment: The same request body (even with the resource being a shared calendar) worked from the graph explorer without issue when logged in as the user.

Comment: Ok, then we're close :). I was worried there was something wrong with the user's mailbox. There's just something specific with how you're app is sending the request. A Fiddler trace (or similar network trace) might help track it down.

Comment: I was able to get this to work using my app code. The key was adding `Calendars.ReadWrite` to the list of scopes we request when the user authorizes our application.

We were under the impression that `Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared` included the standard `Calendars.ReadWrite` scope.

Comment: Hmm. I thought so too :). I'll report it to the right folks.

Answer (score 1):

Self-answer here for anyone having a similar issue who doesn't want to dig through comments.

After some debugging help from Marc LaFleur and Jason Johnston (thanks for the responses!), the answer to my specific question is "sort of".

No, there are no specific `Subscriptions.*` scopes, and they are not needed to create subscription channels.

But, quixotically, the `POST /subscriptions` creation endpoint requires more specific permission scopes than the resource itself.

In my example, the `Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared` permission does indeed allow my app to read and write events to the user's calendars and shared calendars, but I was unable to create a subscription channel for the same calendar.

Requesting the less permissive and more specific scope of `Calendars.ReadWrite` in addition to `Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared` solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this (saved me a bunch of time)!

It is really unfortunate and unintuitive that `Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared` is not adequate on its own. The [permissions documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference) implies that `Calendars.ReadWrite` is a subset of `Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared`. I now have thousands of users that I'll need to re-auth in order to make this work :(

Comment: @Leighton Wallace - What was your resource parameter  `resource": "users/{userPrincipalName}/calendars/{sharedCalendarId}/events` ?