# Handling user-specific shared calendar IDs in Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

When enumerating [calendars](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/calendar?view=graph-rest-1.0) in the Microsoft Graph API, calendars that are shared amongst users have a different `id` per user. How then can we identify unique shared calendars across users?

For example, user A has a calendar, and `/v1.0/me/calendars` returns an object with `id` = `123`. User A has shared that calendar with user B, whose `/v1.0/me/calendars` returns an object with `id` = `456`. How do we know these are actually the same calendar?

The `name` field may be the same (not sure if it can be re-named) but cannot be relied upon to be unique. It looks like [extended properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/singlevaluelegacyextendedproperty?view=graph-rest-1.0) are not shared with the calendar, so setting a unique id in one of those cannot be read by another user.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Microsoft Graph API Shared Calendar IDs inconsistent between users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46943347/microsoft-graph-api-shared-calendar-ids-inconsistent-between-users)